# How do you set a global int inside of a void in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am making a stat code console app in, C++ visual studio 2013.

I have global `int`x set as far as I know, and I have some `void`s made up, the problem is I'm unsure how to set the new global `int` inside of the `void` and reuse the `int` (updated) inside of `int main`.

please help.

```
#include < iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 0;
void change(int x);
void change2(int x);
int main ()
{
change;
system("PAUSE");
change2;
return(0);
}
void change(int x)
{
x = 5;
 cout << x << endl;
}
void change2(int x)
{
x = (5 + 1);
 cout << x << endl;
}
```

I think thats a simplified version

Comment: If you would like the code to review and get back to me i'm happy to post it.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Ofcourse we would like to see the code. Just imagine you are one of us, forget everything you know about your program. Then read your question again. Do you know what its talking about ?

Comment: Its too long by 15000 char

Comment: [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please post code for whatever you've tried yet. We do not spoonfeed here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Whoever keeps teaching people to use "a void" when they mean "a function"... needs to be barred from ever being near a compiler again.

Comment: Function calls look like `func(params)`.  You're not calling any functions in your code.

Comment: In your text you say "... I have a global 'int' s..." but in your sample code your only global 'int' is called x.  You're asking the reader to guess at what you mean - not a good idea if you're looking for help.  be kind to your readers - edit your code to use the variable name s or edit your text to use the variable name x so you are consistent.

Comment: Also you have three variables called x - the 'int' declared immediately after your using statement, the 'int' parameter to the function 'change' and the 'int' parameter to the function 'change2'.  That makes discussion difficult - if I say "<do whatever> to x" which of the three do I mean?  In the 'change' procedure which of the three are you setting to 5?  Use "y" and "z" as parameter names to 'change' and 'change2' respectively it will be easier to reason about the code, you'll be clearer about what you are setting to the value 5 and as @ben points out you'll no longer hide the global

Comment: Int x is the only int i would like in the sample though, shouldn't it be included in the void?

Comment: There is no "the void", "a void", or "some voids". `void` is an abstract type and no instances of it can ever exist. Please call functions by their correct name (which is "function").

Comment: Finally as @retired-ninja points out, if you want to call a function you have to use the () operator.  The statement `change;` does not call the function called "change".  Instead it calculates the address of "change" and then throws the result of that calculation away.  Since `change` is declared to take an int parameter you must pass an int parameter to it when you call it: for example `change (42);` or `change (foo);` assuming you had declared an `int` called "foo" somewhere,

Comment: One other thing I should have mentioned.  If you compile the sample code above in Visual Studio 2013 you should be getting warnings of the form `afilename.cpp(8): warning C4551: function call missing argument list`.  See the Build Output window or the Error List window.  The [C4551 warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksxhyt4e.aspx) is telling you what @retired-ninja said above.  Warnings are usually a bad sign and shouldn't be ignored unless you have a clear idea of why they can be safely ignored in your particular situation.  Even when they can be ignored its better to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter `int x` hides the global variable `int x`, that is why the function doesn't change the global.

You can easily avoid this problem by using different names for each declared variable.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example with the sample code i did above?

Answer (score 0):

okay, let's look at your code ...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int x = 0;              // a global variable.

void change(int x);     // declares a function taking an int, returning void
void change2(int x);    // declares another function with same signature

int main ()
{
  change;               // declare a reference to function change()
                        // no function call: statement has no effect
  system("PAUSE");
  change2;              // declare a reference to function change2()
                        // no function call: statement has no effect
  return(0);
}

void change(int x)      // defines a previously declared function 
{                       // argument x is passed by copy
  x = 5;                // sets local variable x to 5
  cout << x << endl;    // global variable x is not affected
}
void change2(int x)     // defines another previously declared function
{                       // argument x is passed by copy
  x = (5 + 1);          // sets local variable x to 5+1
  cout << x << endl;    // global variable x is not affected
}
```

If you want to change the global variable `x`, then you must not hide it with a local variable (or explicitly change the global variable):

```
int x;                  // global variable
void change_x_to(int i)
{
  x=i;                  // assigns local variable i to global variable x
}

void change2_x_to(int x)
{
  ::x=x;                // assigns local variable x to global variable x
}

int main ()
{
  change_x_to(5);
  change2_x_to(x+1);   // the global x (of course)
  assert(x==6);
}                      // return 0; is automatically created for main()
```

Answer (score -2):

A scope is a region of the program and broadly speaking there are three places, where variables can be declared:

Inside a function or a block which is called local variables,

Outside of all functions which is called global variables.

You cannot declare a global variable inside a local block although,ye you can use a static global block which can hold the last modified value of your variable.

```
#include "example.h"


 int global_foo = 0;
 static int local_foo = 0;


 int foo_function()
 {
 /* sees: global_foo and local_foo
  cannot see: local_bar  */
  return 0;
 }
```

Even his approach is not a good programming practice rather If global variable is to be used across multiple .c files, you should not declare it static. Instead you should declare it extern in header file included by all .c files that need it.

[Refer this for further details.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm)

Comment: "We will learn what is a function and it's parameter in subsequent chapters"? You're posting someone's coding tutorial?

Comment: @kfsone what are you talking about ?

Comment: Your answer seems to be copied directly from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

Comment: Yes,it is. . for better explanation I copied it as I do not have a good command over English.

Comment: I've added what i think a simplified version is.